# Solr stats field on type text

Tags: solr

Im trying to get a stats of field called "Quantity"..The field is stored as a "text". Considering that the index has around 50 million records and its difficult to rebuild the index. Can we somehow tweak the  query to consider the "Quantity" field as int field instead of "text" field..

Query

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/collection1/select?q=usb&wt=json&indent=true&stats=true&stats.field=Quantity_t
```

Error

```
 "error":{
    "msg":"Field type text_general{class=org.apache.solr.schema.TextField,analyzer=org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain,args={class=solr.TextField, positionIncrementGap=100}} is not currently supported",
    "code":400}}
```

Comment: got any solution?

Answer (score 0):

> *The Stats component returns simple statistics for numeric, string, and date fields within the document set.*

The very first line of [documentation](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_1/the-stats-component.html)(version 7.1) of stats component says, stats can only be applied on **numeric, string** and **date** fields.

One solution will be using **string** type for **text_general** field.